# How can i extend Contacts Provider to another app in android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I am creating application is like Viber or Whatsapp.

I want to create contact list from system's contact list in mobile.
The new contact list will get all contacts and create new list with some additional attributes. The new list will store in new database and sync to my server.

How can i extend Contacts Provider attributes and store in new database?

Any solution for this case?

Comment: Make sure you search for possible answers. This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739159/can-i-extend-androids-contacts-database looks similar.

Comment: Thanks @MikeGorski. I saw answers of the question. But it is not what i need. I want to create new contacts list with some more attributes in new database. I do not use system's Contacts Provider.

Comment: why do you want to duplicate data which sooner or later will go out of sync? why not to add the custom attributes only?

Comment: Thanks @pskink, If we add custom attributes to system's contacts, this changes contact details. I do not want this. I want keep system's contact. Data go out of sync. That's sure. I accept it.

Comment: `If we add custom attributes to system's contacts, this changes contact details` what do you mean: "this changes contact details" ?

Comment: @pskink, when we add custom attributes system's contract. The contact list default of system will change attributes. I do not want change those. I need to add custom attributes by new contact list that keep the contact list default. Thanks!

Comment: i still have no idea what you mean...